# Error while adding element to a spacy pipeline

Tags: pipeline, spacy-3

I'm trying to modify spacy pipeline in spacy 3.5. Just
`nlp = spacy.load(spacy_model, disable=['parser']) nlp.add_pipe('morphologizer', before='ner')`

without `initialize()` I've got E109.

Using it, I've got
ValueError: [E955] Can't find table(s) lexeme_norm for language 'en' in spacy-lookups-data. Make sure you have the package installed or provide your own lookup tables if no default lookups are available for your language.

I'll appreciate any help or working snippet of pipeline customization.
Regretably, I've no succeed to find a full example in the spacy docs.